# Visual Studio Build Error - Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'. (APT0000) (test.Droid)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have installed packages for API 16 and 25. I have also installed packages `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 and Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat`. What else could i be missing? Are the version of the packages not matching the API? Below is how everything is configured

**error**

[image]

**Packages**

[image]

**Target version**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What else could i be missing?

Please make sure that you've also downloaded the latest `Extras`, the following is my installed packages of `Extras`:

[image]

Then try to clean and rebuild your project.